# How do import an .sql file in oracle, please see error below

Tags: oracle, import, export

The following happens on every line, I am trying to import this information so I can use it for training:

```
Error starting at line : 1,292 in command -
  ALTER TABLE "HR"."JOB_HISTORY" ADD CONSTRAINT "JHIST_EMP_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID")
      REFERENCES "HR"."EMPLOYEES" ("EMPLOYEE_ID") ENABLE
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 1,294 in command -
  ALTER TABLE "HR"."JOB_HISTORY" ADD CONSTRAINT "JHIST_JOB_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("JOB_ID")
      REFERENCES "HR"."JOBS" ("JOB_ID") ENABLE
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Error starting at line : 1,300 in command -
  ALTER TABLE "HR"."LOCATIONS" ADD CONSTRAINT "LOC_C_ID_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("COUNTRY_ID")
      REFERENCES "HR"."COUNTRIES" ("COUNTRY_ID") ENABLE
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: It simply means that one of the tables which are referred here does not exists in your DB

Comment: it can only mean that the table exists but you don't have the privileges run ALTER TAB LE on it. What is the user account that is used to run this script ?

Comment: There are many possibilities here, like schema doesn't exist, you don't have privilege, schema mapping required etc. Unless you tell us how was the export done and how you are importing it, no way to tell precisely what's wrong.

Comment: Which tool are you using to 'import' this, and which user are you running it as - HR or someone else? And how was the script generated? Have you already created the tables and are just trying to add the foreign keys to them, or is the script creating everything and you've only shown part of it? (The line numbers in the errors suggest it's a much bigger script... but we don't know what else it's doing.)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ALL_TABLES WHERE OWNER = 'HR';
```

Do you see entries for JOB_HISTORY, EMPLOYEES, JOBS, LOCATIONS, and COUNTRIES?

If not, either

You need to create those tables, OR
You need SELECT and ALTER privs on those tables to be granted to you, OR
Your tables are in a schema OTHER than HR, and you need to figure out the right schema to run these scripts in.

Comment: by the way i hate using an ANSWER as a substitute for a more verbose comment, but i don't see a better way...

Comment: agree 100%.  I think it serious weakness in the SE/SO platform that one cannot do the kind of formatting in 'comments' that one can do in 'answers'.  Even Jive does a better job.  ;-)